# View bitcoins per address in MultiBit

Tags: wallet, address, multibit

I have a wallet with 100 addresses in MultiBit. From what I've gathered, bitcoins are linked to a specific address. Is there a way to see in MultiBit how much of my balance belongs to each address?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this functionality has not been implemented yet in Multibit. The only way to check individual balances is to via blockchain.info.  A real pain if you have 100 addresses.

Also it's not possible to specify which addresses to spend from when making a transaction from a wallet that has multiple addresses.  So need to have multiple wallets with loads of passwords - torture.

It is supposed to be possible with Bitcoin to use addresses once and then discard them.  But with multibit this isn't feasible yet in practice.

These features will come soon either to Multibit or another wallet.  They are badly needed.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to choose 1 address out of them.... send ALL your bitcoins to your own address and this would organize it for you. Now query blockchain and that one address should have all the worth of bitcoins which should be equal to the figure being shown by multibit.